# Auto-renewing subscription iOS swift Decide to give Free Trial

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, trial, auto-renewing

here is my "Problem", I have an Product with a one year Trial and the same product without trial. Is there a way to use only the Product with 1 year free trial and decide to who I give the trial?
If there is a way, is that allowed? I want to give the trial only to people that has bought that product in Android. So they can use the same functions without buying the product again. I will tell them that they can cancel the subscription 1 day before the trial ends.New user will buy the product but the trial won't be given to them. I hope you guys can Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it technically possible?** Kind of. You could *conditionally* show only 1 of the 2 available IAPs to your users in your app's UI. However, in the App Store users will always be able to see **all**¹ In-App Purchases you have configured in iTunes Connect. So that might be a bit confusing for your users.

**Is it allowed?** That's more of a grey zone. The [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#business) don't *explicitly* mention it but that is never a guarantee. There is mention of *cross-platform considerations* in the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html), but it's more in the context of sharing functionality between macOS and iOS:

> [...] You could let users who have a subscription in an iOS app access the content from a macOS app (or vice versa), but **implementing that functionality is your responsibility. You would need a system to identify users and keep track of the content they are subscribed to**, similar to what you would implement for an app that uses non-renewable subscriptions.

---

¹ : On iOS 11 you can choose to [promote certain IAPs](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/promoting-in-app-purchases/):

> You can choose to promote up to 20 in-app purchases at a time on your
>   product page, with additional in-app purchases approved and ready to
>   promote. **This gives you the flexibility to change the in-app purchases
>   that appear on your product page** at any time based on your business
>   needs — for example, if you’re planning to launch a limited-time price
>   promotion or offer exclusive content.

I'm not sure that will completely *hide* non-promoted IAPs though. I have yet to finish watching the [What's New in StoreKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/) WWDC session :)

Comment: Do u know if it is possible to deactivate the trial for some users in code, but than again I don't think that would be allowed :D

Comment: No, that's not possible *nor* allowed. That would be very user hostile :o